# Accessing ejb deployed in JBoss 7.0.1 from another client

Tags: jboss, ejb

Having deployed an EJB module in JBoss 7.0.1, I am trying to access it from a client executing on another JVM. However, I am unable to figure out the client side jars needed to add to my client's classpath.

I tried out with the following:-

1. jboss-ejb-api_3.1_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar
2. jboss-ejb-client-1.0.0.Beta11.jar 
   3.jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2.jar
3. jboss-marshalling-1.3.4.GA.jar 
   5.jboss-marshalling-river-1.3.4.GA.jar
4. jboss-remoting-3.2.0.CR8.jar 
   7.jboss-sasl-1.0.0.Beta9.jar
5. jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
6. xnio-api-3.0.0.CR7.jar

There seems to be some inconsistency in this setup and I get this exception:-

> INFO: JBoss EJB Client version 1.0.0.Beta11 Nov 9, 2012 12:01:04 AM
>   org.xnio.Xnio  INFO: XNIO Version 3.0.0.CR7 Nov 9, 2012
>   12:01:04 AM org.jboss.ejb.client.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector
>   createConnections ERROR: Could not create connection for connection
>   named default java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No matching XNIO
>   provider found    at org.xnio.Xnio.doGetInstance(Xnio.java:192)   at
>   org.xnio.Xnio.getInstance(Xnio.java:146)  at
>   org.jboss.remoting3.Remoting.createEndpoint(Remoting.java:73)
>
> ...

I didn't have any issues while having a client access an ejb deployed in JBoss 7.1.0 Final, JBoss 6.1.0 Final or Glassfish servers. The jars required at the client side war available.

I am a newbie in Java EE and Application Servers by the way and I am trying to learn in the process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

please add xnio-nio-3.0.3.GA.jar in your classpath

Comment: Thanx, this saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to Ramkumar's answer, I am adding the maven dependency for this jar. Following the maven dependency for the jar:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.xnio</groupId>
    <artifactId>xnio-nio</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.3.GA</version>
</dependency>
```